# Change line style of contour lines in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I have a problem regarding the contour lines that pgfplots can add to 3D plots. I want the contour lines to be dashed instead of solid. I've attached a small example from the pgfplots manual where I want the black lines to be dashed.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    enlargelimits=false,
    3d box=complete

]
\addplot3[surf]
{x^2-y^2};
20
0
5
−20
0
−4 −2
0
x
2
4
−5
y
\addplot3[
contour gnuplot={contour dir=y,
draw color=red,labels=false},
y filter/.expression={-5}
] {x^2-y^2};
\addplot3[
contour gnuplot={contour dir=x,
draw color=blue,labels=false},
x filter/.expression={5}
] {x^2-y^2};
\addplot3[
contour gnuplot={contour dir=z,
draw color=black,labels=false},
z filter/.expression={25}
] {x^2-y^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `dashed` in

```
\addplot3[
contour gnuplot={contour dir=z,
draw color=black,labels=false},
z filter/.expression={25},dashed   %%<-------
] {x^2-y^2};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    enlargelimits=false,
    3d box=complete
]
\addplot3[surf]
{x^2-y^2}; 
\addplot3[
contour gnuplot={contour dir=y,
draw color=red,labels=false},
y filter/.expression={-5}
] {x^2-y^2};
\addplot3[
contour gnuplot={contour dir=x,
draw color=blue,labels=false},
x filter/.expression={5}
] {x^2-y^2};
\addplot3[
contour gnuplot={contour dir=z,
draw color=black,labels=false},
z filter/.expression={25},dashed
] {x^2-y^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's possible make `contour dir=-x` or something like that to show the contour lines in background plane YZ?

Comment: @juanuni: Change `5` to `-5` in `x filter/.expression={5}`, Similarly in `y` and `z` filter expressions change the sign. Also you may want to change the order of `\addplot3` commands.